# How to post to multiple database tables with 1 to many relationships

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

I have a semi-complex database with multiple tables (3) that I'd like to post data to.

Rules of database

1. Each experiment (experiment table) can have multiple varibles associated with it (1 to many)
2. Each variable (variable table) can have multiple values (value table) (1 to many).

Sample DB Structure

**experiment table**

exprid (pk - auto_increment)

pagetype

pagename

expresult

**variable table**

varid (pk - auto_increment)

image

varresult

exprid (fk)

**value table**

valueid (pk - auto_increment)

image

valueresult

varid (fk)

I'm setting up a form that accepts inputs that will post to the appropriate tables, however I am having a hard time understanding how I can get this to work properly.

**Here's essentially what I'd like to do:**

1. User enters experiment details
2. User enters details for variable 1 (that info is associated with the experiment)
3. User enters details for value 1 (that info is associated with variable 1)
4. user submits value 1 to value table
5. User enters details for value 2 (that info is associated with variable 1)
6. user submits value 2 to value table
7. user is finished entering values for variable 1
8. User creates new variable in order to enter new values
9. Repeat steps 2-6

**Ultimately, I am unsure how to:**
a) post to the appropriate tables 
b) ensure the visitor does not have to enter the experiment details once a value or variable is submitted

**The ask:**

It would be great if someone can help me understand the logic that goes into something like this.  I really don't even know where to start because all of the forms I've built so far require me to only post to 1 table.  So written logic would be helpful.

Any links to posts about this topic or articles online, any instructions on how to tackle or even sample code would be helpful.  At this point, I think anything would be helpful if I can just get an idea of where to start.

Answer (score 0):

So after each submit (via ajax request) you have to extend your list of fields.

If you're using jQuery I would suggest to have a look at it's ajax methods: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

When the data is submitted dynamically add your fields, there are dozens of tutorials, like: http://www.infotuts.com/dynamically-add-input-fields-to-form-jquery/

That's all, so in the end you'll have multiple requests which always store your new added data and skip the reload of the pages, as ajax is done in the background.

Comment: Cool. I'll give this a shot and see where I get. Thanks for the initial input!

Comment: I guess my only question is, when I click submit associated with value level data, how is it going to know to eventually associate that record in the value table, with the record in the variable table, with the record in the experiments table?  If the "experiment" isn't actually submitted yet, how will it know to associate the ID's in each table?  Perhaps the process is "on submit" create a record in the experiments table, store that id, create a record in the variable table (associate the experimentid) and then create the first value (and associated with the variable id)

Comment: Your approach of createing experiment record on the first run is right. store that id and associate more variable/values later